# onDestroy in Android service

Tags: android, android-service

I have a long running service which responds to multiple `BroadcastReceivers` (created in code, not manifest). Most of the time the service is running well, but from time to time it gets somehow stopped (the `BroadcastReceivers` stop to work) - I guess the system pauses it somehow (when I look into the running processes on the device I can clearly see the service is still "runnning").

I don't know the right reason why the service is being paused, but I'd like to know whether in these cases the `onDestroy()` method is called or whether there's a chance to handle this somehow.

I presume `onDestroy()` is not being called, because the service is still visible in the Running processes tab. I also have the service return the `START_STICKY` flag so the system should restart it whenever it's killed for memory reasons. Also if it is "paused" somehow, is it possible to create a `WakeLock` for this not to occur?

I know that the best solution would be to put all the `BroadcastReceivers` into the manifest and create a one shot-service called from their `onReceive()` methods. However I have chosen to go with the way of long running service because the initialization stage is very  intensive it's better to initialize everything just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**onDestroy()** will be called only when service is being killed by lack of resources or when you explicitly stop it.

The service can be "paused" when your phone goes idle (usually when screen is off) because the CPU stops. To make services run always you should use **PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK** - but use it wisely because it does not stop your CPU and thus draining the battery. You should never leave your apps running always. Just do what you need holding a *WakeLock* and then release it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

You can use AlarmManager to "wake" your apps periodically and do something.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the Service does nothing most of the time but only responds to the BroadcastReceivers. I would prefer to put the WakeLocks into the onReceive() methods. But since the service gets paused the onReceive methods don't even get fired so the WakeLock inside won't come in use either, am I right?

Comment: @NumberFour never tried this. Try to acquire a WakeLock immediately after onReceive is triggered. If it woun't work try to register a static receiver (in manifest) and see if it wakes.